# Making Google Calendar agenda view into cards

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-calendar-api, mobirise

I'm using Mobirise to build our club's website, and they want to show some of our events at the top of the page.

I thought I could make something like this, with the outer blue being where the calendar frame would end (very rough drawing, don't judge too hard).[image: example of event calendar]

Tockify had something pretty close, but I figured there's a way to code something like this, or perhaps another service that's free that can do this. I would prefer not to use PHP, but embed some JavaScript into the HTML that can do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve events from an account's calendar, you need to connect to the Google Calendar API using authorized credentials.

For this you need to create a project in Google Cloud Platform, and enable the calendar API for that project. You will also need to create credentials for your app to use when making calls to the API.

After you have a project, credentials and you have enabled the Calendar API, it is time to code a script that uses the credentials to get the data you want from the Calendar API.

There are several language client libraries for each developer's need. You could use JavaScript for your application.

Here is a quickstart that should get you up and running to make those Calendar API calls you are looking for.

- [Calendar API Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/js)